# Простая программа на QT(C++) падает с сегфолтом без видимых причин

Tags: c++, qt

Падение происходит на выделении памяти в конструкторе класса, подозрения на то, что это связано с неправильной работой с `QHBoxLayout`.Притом, если сам объект класса создавать динамически, то программа работает.

**main.cpp**

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include "copytext.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QLabel lbl;

     /*
    CopyText tmp;  // падает
    tmp.show();*/

    CopyText*tmp = new CopyText(); //работает
    tmp->show();

     return app.exec();
}
```

**copytext.h**

```
#ifndef COPYTEXT_H
#define COPYTEXT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class CopyText:public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    CopyText(QWidget* prnt = nullptr);
private:
     QTextEdit* txt;
     QLabel* lbl;
     QHBoxLayout* lt;
private slots:
     void textChange();
};

#endif // COPYTEXT_H
```

**copytext.cpp**

```
#include "copytext.h"

CopyText::CopyText(QWidget *prnt):QWidget(prnt)
{

    lt = new QHBoxLayout();  //место падения
    txt = new QTextEdit();
    lbl = new QLabel();

    lt->addWidget(txt);
    lt->addWidget(lbl);

   this->setLayout(lt);

   connect(this->txt,SIGNAL(textChanged()),SLOT(textChange()));
}

void CopyText::textChange(){
    lbl->setText(txt->toPlainText());
}
```

Comment: а так же работает при явной передаче пустого указателя  `CopyText tmp(nullptr);`

Comment: Проверил у себя в VS2015, Qt5.7, x86 - работает и тот, и другой вариант. Не вижу причин для падения. Скачайте сурсы, посмотрите, что там в конструкторе происходит

Comment: Дебагером, разумеется

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, ошибка исчезла при переносе в другой проект.

Comment: Осталось разобраться, в чем была проблема с тем проектом, что там падало, а тут нет